# Помогите пожалуйста с кодировкой

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, кодировка

Отправляю аякс запрос на сервер

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "ajax/diet.php",
data:{
...
  food: dishObj //Объект {dish: "Бананы", weight: 0, portions: 1}
}
...
});
```

На сервере получаю что-то вроде

```
$food = $_POST['food'];
var_dump($food);    //["dish"]=> string(12) "Р‘Р°РЅР°РЅС‹" ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" ["portions"]=> string(1) "1"
```

Короче кириллица не правильно кодируется. Я ставил content-type utf-8 в html, header utf-8 на сервере и в html, ставил charset скрипту, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

У файла **ajax/diet.php** сделайте кодировку **utf-8 без bom**

(кодировку самого содержимого файла)

*В Notepad++ делается так:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]